# Can not iterate over vector of structs: a collection of type std::vec::Vec<Foo> cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type &Foo

Tags: rust

I'm trying to build a simple HTTP server with Rocket that loads data from an external database. Each endpoint will provide a filtered and sorted subset of the data set that is loaded when starting the server.

This works fine in that I can pass the `Vec<Media>` around.

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#![plugin(rocket_codegen)]


extern crate rusted_cypher;
extern crate rocket;
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket_contrib;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_json;

use std::fmt::Debug;
use rusted_cypher::GraphClient;
use rocket_contrib::{JSON, Value};
use rocket::State;


// this works
#[get("/")]
fn index(data: State<Vec<Media>>) -> JSON<Value> {
    JSON(json!(data.inner()))
}



fn loadData() -> Vec<Media> {
    let graph = GraphClient::connect("http://server:7474/db/data").unwrap();
    let results = graph.exec("MATCH (m:SIMPLEFIED) RETURN m").unwrap();
    let mut data: Vec<Media> = Vec::new();
    for row in results.rows() {
        data.push(Media {
                      id: row.get("m.id").unwrap(),
                      rating: row.get("m.rating").unwrap(),
                      release_date: row.get("releaseDate").unwrap(),
                  });
    }

    data
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Media {
    id: String,
    rating: u16,
    release_date: i32,
}

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite()
        .manage(loadData())
        .mount("/", routes![index])
        .launch();
}
```

However, when I want to iterate over the vector to `f`

```
// simple release date filter for release date greater than <d>
#[get("/gt/<d>")]
fn gt(d: i32, data: State<Vec<Media>>) -> JSON<Value> {
    let v = data.inner();
    let out = v.iter()
        .filter(|m| m.release_date > d)
        .collect::<Vec<Media>>();
    JSON(json!(out))
}
```

I get this error

> error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<Media>:
>   std::iter::FromIterator<&Media>` is not satisfied

(...)

> the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<&Media>` is not implemented for
>   `std::vec::Vec

and the somewhat helpful note

> a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<Media>` cannot be built from an
>   iterator over elements of type `&Media`

Comment: You are iterating over over a `&Vec<T>`, which produces values of type `&T`. There's no way to "automatically" go from `&T` to `T`. Chances are good you want to `clone` the items, as discussed in the linked duplicate. You may also wish to collect to a `Vec<&T>`, if that type can be expressed in JSON. You can just use `collect::<Vec<_>>()` in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That solved it for me.